# Non-working if statement

Tags: java, string, comparison, reference

I have this code:

```
Node main_node = document.getDocumentElement();
NodeList main_node_list = main_node.getChildNodes();
for( int main_iterator = 0; main_iterator < main_node_list.getLength(); main_iterator++ ) {
    Node child_node = main_node_list.item( main_iterator );
    String child_node_name = child_node.getNodeName();
    if( child_node_name == "#text" ) continue;
    Toast.makeText( context, "\"" + child_node_name + "\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    if( child_node_name == "library_visual_scenes" ) {
    ...
    }
}
```

It can't be any clearer, but in the Toast between the two if statements, it shows that child_node_name is exactly equal "library_visual_scenes" at some point.  This without the second if statement being true.

The first if statement, when child_node_name is equal "#text" does get executed.  Meaning I never see the text "#text" in the Toast.

child_node_name is a String object.  Is this the correct way to compare a String with a character string?

I cannot find out what's going on here.  Could this be some Android specific thing, as nearly the same code works if I run it as plain Java on my computer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
child_node_name == "library_visual_scenes"
child_node_name == "#text"
```

With

```
"library_visual_scenes".equals(child_node_name);
"#text".equals(child_node_name);
```

That is how you must compare Strings in java. "==" compares references, not contents.

Comment: If this isn't the most common novice java programmer mistake, it has to be close.

Comment: Thanx! I see you use "text".equals(String) and not String.equals("text"). Is there a prefered way?

Comment: @Espen well, "text".equals(some_variable) can save you (prevent possible NullPointerEception) in situation when some_variable is null. So I think that is preferred way in case your are not totally sure that it is safe to invoke some_variabe.equals()

Comment: @Espen More about `"text".equals()` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240854/java-xx-equalsvariable-better-than-variable-equalsxx-true

Answer (score 2):

Change the following lines to use the `equals` method:

```
if( child_node_name.equals("#text") ) continue;
```

and

```
if( child_node_name.equals("library_visual_scenes") ) {
```